# PlatformNotSupportedException when establishing a TCP connection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 I found that my existing Xamarin application wasn't able to establish TCP connections anymore.

After some research I found that Visual Studio 2019 also came with MSBuild 16 when VS2017 had MSBuild 15.

before I was using this piece of code after generating a certificate and key pair for my RSA system cryptography:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(bcCert)) 
    { PrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keyPair.Private) };
```

With Visual Studio 2019 you can't set the private key. This can be seen in the decompiled X509Certificate2.cs in
`C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MicrosoftVisualStudio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll`

Following this [repo](https://github.com/CryptLink/CertBuilder/blob/master/CertBuilder.cs) I found a `ConvertBouncyCert` method that would return an `X509Certificate2` wrapper around my generated X509Certificate which would have the private key attached but I was still getting an `unable to decode` exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeremy's library contains this code for converting an X509Certificate into an X509Certificate2:

```
            var pkcs12Store = new Pkcs12Store();
            var certEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(BouncyCert);

            pkcs12Store.SetCertificateEntry(BouncyCert.SerialNumber.ToString(), certEntry);
            pkcs12Store.SetKeyEntry(BouncyCert.SerialNumber.ToString(),
                new AsymmetricKeyEntry(KeyPair.Private), new[] { certEntry });

            X509Certificate2 keyedCert;

            using (MemoryStream pfxStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                pkcs12Store.Save(pfxStream, null, new SecureRandom());
                pfxStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                keyedCert = new X509Certificate2(pfxStream.ToArray(), "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            }

            return keyedCert;
```

You need to create a Pkcs12StoreBuilder object and set the DER encoding to true.

```
            var pkcs12StoreBuilder = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder();

            pkcs12StoreBuilder.SetUseDerEncoding(true);
            var pkcs12Store = pkcs12StoreBuilder.Build();

            var certificateEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(bouncyCert);
```

This [article](https://www.cryptologie.net/article/260/asn1-vs-der-vs-pem-vs-x509-vs-pkcs7-vs/) does a great job at explaining DER and all the components around it within cryptography and RSA systems.